# Количество товаров в Opencart само изменяется на 1000 штук при редактировании товара в админке

Tags: opencart, редактор, админка, save

При редактировании товара в админке после нажатия на кнопку "Сохранить", количество само изменяется на 1000 штук, хотя я количество не менял. Это значение (1000 штук) приходит в функцию productEdit($product_id) в файле /admin/modeles/catalog/product.php .

Как мне исправить эту проблему? Подскажите, пожалуйста! Заранее благодарен за ответы.

Comment: Я сделал следующим образом:

В методе edit контроллера /admin/controllers/catalog/product изменил следующее:

if (isset($this->request->get['filter_quantity'])) {
    
    $url .= '&filter_quantity=' . $this->request->get['filter_quantity'];
   } else {
    $prod = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($this->request->get['product_id']);
    $url .= '&filter_quantity=' . $prod['quantity'];
   }
Сейчас в 10-00 приду на работу и проверю работает ли.

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле это не так решается.

Просто нужно в методе edit контроллера /admin/controllers/catalog/product заменить:

```
$post = $this->request->post;

        if(!isset($post['quantity']) || !$post['quantity'] || $post['quantity'] == 1000){
            $prod = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($this->request->get['product_id']);
            $post['quantity'] = $prod['quantity'];
        }

        $this->model_catalog_product->editProduct($this->request->get['product_id'], $post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто тот сотрудник, который раньше работал над сайтом, обозлился на этого клиента и решил подпортить сайт в некоторых местах. Одно из таких мест - тот вопрос, который я задал. Просто этот человек во вьюхе \admin\view\template\catalog\product_form.tpl стояло раньше вот так:

```
<div class="form-group hidden">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-quantity"><?php echo $entry_quantity; ?></label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo '1000'/* $quantity */; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo '1000'/* $entry_quantity */; ?>" id="input-quantity" class="form-control" />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Я всё это исправил.